# Page Speed Test Score Showing 0 or 1 for Mobile devices

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed-insights-api

Our website is on magento 2 and we did all kind of speed optimisations in the website. But the page speed score of the website on mobile device is showing 0 or sometimes it shows 1.
Can someone please help us to identify the issue?
This happens only with Google page speed test tool.
The URL of the website is https://www.amouage.com/

[page speed test tool -  screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbSMM.png)

Comment: The whole point of the tool is that it tells you what is wrong further down the page. I just ran the test on Lighthouse in the browser - you get 3. No idea what optimisations you haver done but the page comes in at 9MB (20MB unzipped) so start with page weight. Next you have way way way to much javascript running. I mean just follow the items under "Opportunities" and "diagnostics" and ask questions about each as you learn / get stuck (you can click each item and it opens with links to pages that explain). As it stands this question is too broad and so it will probably get closed.

Comment: Finally your score is low in Page Speed Insights (PSI) compared to something like GT Metrix as PSI simulates a 4G connection - so large pages suffer because of simulated latency and simulated slower speeds.